# How to get the direction along a street?

Tags: ios, google-maps, mapkit, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I have a street address, say, 1234 Main Street. How can I get the direction of street, at this address? By direction, I mean direction in degrees, for example north is 0 degree, east is 90 degree, etc.

The purpose of this, is to get the facing direction of the house sitting at that location. (assume all houses are facing its street)

Originally, I am trying to implement this functionality in an iOS project. But advice on any general API to use (e.g. apple provided api such as mapkit, or third-party api, or google-maps, openstreetmap) are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use the google maps api, to find the direction of the streets. Then just determine which side of the road the house is on by it's coordinates. Hope this helped.